# Program not running from expected directory?

Tags: java

I am working on a web-based program, using Java.  I am not sure exactly how to phrase this, but I expect the program to be running from within the c:/Resin/webapps/apps directory.  However, when I reference a file in the program like this: "../files/randomfile.pdf", it cannot find that file.  It works when I reference it like this: "c:/Resin/webapps/files/randomfile.pdf".  How to I change the "running location"? (And what is the technical term for this?)

```
try {
    Document iTextDoc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 27, 27, 35, 18);
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) pageContext.getResponse();
    res.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-word");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ".rtf;");

    RtfWriter2 rtfWriter = RtfWriter2.getInstance(iTextDoc, res.getOutputStream());     
    iTextDoc.open();
    iTextDoc.add(new Paragraph ("Testing RTF Letterhead with Logo"));

    // Use full classname to avoid ambiguity with java.awt.Image
    com.lowagie.text.Image logoImg = com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance("../files/someimage.jpg");
    logoImg.setAlignment(Image.RIGHT | Image.TEXTWRAP);
    iTextDoc.add(logoImg);
    iTextDoc.add(new Paragraph ("Put other information about organization beneath logo"));
    iTextDoc.close();
}
```

I get the following error with the resulting file: Adobe Reader could not open 'someFile.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).

However, if I change the getInstance command to this:

```
com.lowagie.text.Image logoImg = com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance("webapps/files/someimage.jpg");
```

it works.  So my guess is that the working directory (thanks for the term) needs to be set somewhere.  I am using Resin -- any idea where I should be setting this?

Thanks!

Comment: "running location" is usually referred to as the working directory, which may not be the directory the application sits it.  How are you referencing the files (code snippet please)?  The problem might be that the app's directory is not in the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a java program you can't change the running location.

First you should find out where your program is running. You can do this by calling

```
System.out.println( new File( "." ).getAbsolutePath() );
```

Now you can specify your paths relative to this directory.

Comment: -1 because the answer using "user.dir" is better and had less votes that this.

Comment: @Daniel, you are right. I just didn't know about the property "user.dir". I'll upvote kgiannakakis answer, too.
@twpc: You should better accept kgiannakakis answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably referring to the user.dir [system](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) property, which is read only. Relative paths use this as the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

From the [java.io.File](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) doc

> By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the **current user directory**. This directory is named by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked.

Broadly speaking, you should not rely on the current directory for locating files. Use full (absolute) paths, if possible (but without harcoding it in you application, of course). if the file is inside a webapp tree (or just inside the classpath), you might want to take a look at [findResource()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findResource(java.lang.String)) and related methods.